# Boolean Expression - ((a'.b)'+c')' + (a'+(b'.c)')'

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying out one of the exercise, but not sure whether did I get the answer right, is the answer for the following output is 'C'?
Kindly help to simplified it, as I'm not sure about it, still trying hard to learn.

```
Simplify the following boolean expression using boolean algebra.
    ((a'.b)'+c')' + (a'+(b'.c)')'
```

Answer (score 1):

((a' b)' + c')' + (a' + (b' c)')'
= (a' b) c + a (b' c)
= a'b c + a b'c
= (a'b + a b') c
= (a xor b) c